# Проверка предыдущего символа. Регулярные выражения

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Как сделать проверку последнего введенного символа с помощью регулярного выражения? Например, если предыдущий символ в строке является цифрой 3, то следующий символ может быть числом от 0 до 6, иначе от 0 до 9.

Answer (score 2):

Можно проверить последние два символа в строке, которую вводите на то, что там действительно цифры и они удовлетворяют условию:

```
/(3[0-6]|[0-24-9]\d)$/
```